# MIPS assembly language - how / where to store numbers?

Tags: assembly, mips

for my school project i have to make a simple program in MARS 4.5 in assembly language. So far what is confusing me is storing numbers. In this program i have to store 2 numbers of what the user inputs. so far this is my code...

```
.data

.text
    main:
        jal GetUserInput
        li $v0, 10
        syscall

GetUserInput:
    #get the input
    li $v0, 5
    syscall

    #move the input
    move $t0, $v0

    #display the input
    li $v0, 1
    move $a0, $t0
    syscall
```

so in the main function it will run the getuserinput function, it will then get the input and move it to $t0. does this mean in c# terms its basicily a variable "int $t0 = 10" providing 10 is the number i inputted and i can change that number later on in the program? now if i wanted 2 stored numbers, what would i store the other one in, $t1? im new to assembly language

Answer (score 1):

You may store the numbers in various registers (such as t0, t1, ...) but you may also store the numbers in memory.

If you use a C compiler for MIPS and switch off optimization the resulting code will probably store the values in memory.

In fact the MIPS CPU is one of the CPUs that provides the largest "freedom" for the programmer (or compiler).

Answer (score 0):

What your function is doing is taking an input, temporarily saving it, and printing that input on the console. To store multiple numbers, you may need to form a function that returns a specific integer, which is fairly simple.

It is common on MIPS processors to use `$v0` for function return values. Of course, you're free to come up with any calling convention you want for your own functions, but unless you have a very good reason not to I'd say stick with `$v0` for return values.

In order to call a function, use `jal`, because that's what sets up the `$ra` register so that you later can return with `jr $ra`.

So in order to store two integers, your code will be as follows:

```
    .data
    
    .text
        main:
            jal GetUserInput
            add $s0,$s0,$v0
            li $v0, 1
            move $a0,$s0
            syscall
    
            jal GetUserInput
            add $s1,$s1,$v0
            li $v0, 1
            move $a0,$s0
            syscall
    
            li $v0, 10 #End program
            syscall
    
    GetUserInput:
        li $v0, 5 #Get the input
        syscall
        jr $ra
```

Comment: Your main doesn't set `$s0` to anything before adding `$v0` into it.  Did you maybe mean `add $s0, $zero, $v0`, aka `move $s0, $v0`?

Answer (score 0):

To store any value you don't necessarily need to use registers, you can store as many value in as many variables you make inside the .data section. This not only helps you write code efficiently, but also makes registers free, which can be used without having fear of losing values.

```
.data

# Declare as many variables as you want, so that you have more registers in hand
num1:           .word 0             # Number data type initially setting equals to zero
num2:           .word 0
line_feed:      .asciiz "\n"        # Line feed in order to change line.
print_command:  .asciiz "Showing you number: "
ask_user:       .asciiz "Enter number: "

.text

.globl mian

main:
    # Taking input form user
    jal take_input              
    sw $v0, num1                # Storing user input to variable. 

    jal take_input
    sw $v0, num2                # Storing user input to variable.

    # Printing first number
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, print_command
    syscall
    lw $t0, num1
    li $v0, 1
    move $a0, $t0
    syscall
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, line_feed
    syscall

    # Printing second number
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, print_command
    syscall
    lw $t0, num2
    li $v0, 1
    move $a0, $t0
    syscall
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, line_feed
    syscall
    
# Exit Block In order to prevent infinite loop writing it befoere other procedures.
exit:
    li $v0, 10
    syscall

# A porcedure to take input form user
take_input:
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, ask_user
    syscall
    li $v0, 5
    syscall
    jr $ra
```

Comment: Storing and reloading everything to static storage is *not* more efficient than using registers.  It might be simpler to write, but it takes more instructions and loads can cause stalls in the pipeline.  I guess you meant human efficiency in terms of time to write the program, though, not efficiency of the program.  However, this doesn't scale: using global variables for everything doesn't work well in large programs, and isn't re-entrant let alone thread-safe.